# A component is changing the uncontrolled value state of Select to be controlled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to create a edit form to edit data from database by id. I tried this:

```
    import React, {FormEvent, useEffect, useState} from "react";
    import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
    import { createStyles, makeStyles, Theme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
    import {
      TicketFullDTO,
      TicketStatusTypesDTO,
    } from "../../service/support/types";
    import {
      getTicket,
      getTicketStatusTypes,
      updateTicket,
    } from "../../service/support";
    import { useHistory, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
    import InputLabel from "@mui/material/InputLabel";
    import Select from "@mui/material/Select";
    import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
    import { FormControl } from "@mui/material";
    import { Moment } from "moment";
    import { RouteParams } from "../../service/utils";
       
    export default function TicketProfile(props: any) {
      const classes = useStyles();
      let history = useHistory();
      let requestParams = useParams<RouteParams>();

      const [status, setStatus] = useState<string>("");
      const [submitDate, setSubmitDate] = useState<Moment | null>(null);
      const [ticket, setTicket] = useState<TicketFullDTO>();
    
      const formSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e);

        updateTicket(requestParams.id, data)
          .then(({ data }) => {
            console.log(data.title);
            history.replace("/support");
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      };
    
      const [ticketCategoriesList, setTicketCategoriesList] = useState<
        TicketCategoryTypesDTO[]
      >([]);
      const [ticket, setTicket] = useState<TicketFullDTO>();
            
      const getSingleTicket = async () => {
        getTicket(requestParams.id)
          .then(({ data }) => {
            setTicket(data);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      };
    
      const [ticketStatusList, setTicketStatusList] = useState<
        TicketStatusTypesDTO[]
      >([]);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        ticketStatusData();
        getSingleTicket();
      }, []);
    
      const ticketStatusData = async () => {
        getTicketStatusTypes()
          .then((resp) => {
            setTicketStatusList(resp.data);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      };
    
      return (
        <Container>
            <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>

                          .........

                          <TextField
                            value={ticket?.title}
                            id="title"                                             
                            onChange={({ target: { value } }) => {
                              setTicket({ ...ticket, title: value });
                            }}
                          />

                          .........

                          <FormControl>
                            <TextField
                              label="Submit Date"
                              id="submit-date"
                              type="date"
                              defaultValue={ticket?.submitDate}                             
                              //@ts-ignore
                              onInput={(e) => setSubmitDate(e.target.value)}
                            />
                          </FormControl>
                       
                          ..........

                            <Select
                              labelId="status-label"
                              id="status-helper"
                              value={ticket?.status}
                              onChange={(e) => setStatus(e.target.value)}
                              required
                            >
                              {ticketStatusList.map((element) => (
                                <MenuItem value={element.code}>
                                  {element.name}
                                </MenuItem>
                              ))}
                            </Select>
                          </FormControl>

                         ...........
                      
                          <Button
                            type="submit"
                          >
                            Update Ticket
                          </Button>                       
    
        </Container>
      );
    }


.....


export async function updateTicket(
    id: string,
    data: TicketFullDTO
): Promise<AxiosResponse<TicketFullDTO>> {
  return await axios.post<TicketFullDTO>(
      `${baseUrl}/management/support/tickets/ticket/${id}`,
      {
        data,
      }
  );
}

export interface TicketFullDTO {
    id?: number,
    title?: string,
    status?: string,
    submitDate?: Moment | null
}
```

I get error in Chrome console:

`MUI: A component is changing the uncontrolled value state of Select to be controlled. Elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled Select element for the lifetime of the component. The nature of the state is determined during the first render. It's considered controlled if the value is not` undefined`.`

The value for `Select` should be selected using the value `ticket?.status` when list `ticketStatusList` But the data object is not running before rendering the UI content and the value into Select dropdown is not selected.

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Not sure when you update your data. Actually you should always the useEffect hook. Did you try to use `defaultValue={submitDate}` instead of `value`?

Comment: Looks like this solves the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @PeterPenzov Do you still have any problems with this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
                            <Select
                              labelId="status-label"
                              id="status-helper"
                              value={status}
                              onChange={(e) => setStatus(e.target.value)}
                              required
                            >
```

And to synchronize `status` ticket with `ticket` state

```
      const [status, setStatus] = useState<string>("");
      const [submitDate, setSubmitDate] = useState<Moment | null>(null);
      const [ticket, setTicket] = useState<TicketFullDTO>();
      React.useEffect(() => setTicket(previousTicket => 
          ({ ...previousTicket, status })), [status]);
```

Answer (score 12):

React figures out if a component is controlled or not by checking if `value` is set on the first render. `defaultValue` should only be used for uncontrolled components.

Since you're working with controlled components you must provide a default value other than `undefined` in the `value` prop:

```js
<Select
    labelId="status-label"
    id="status-helper"
    value={ticket?.status ?? null}
    onChange={(e) => setStatus(e.target.value)}
    required
>
```

More on this topic in [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html).

Comment: I mane the code change but for this line `onChange={(e) => setStatus(e.target.value)}` I get `TS2345: Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<string>'.   Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<string>'.` Is there any solution?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Typescript, sorry

Comment: Another approach is to use an empty string instead of null as default value, that would satisfy Typescript

Comment: Can you guide me how this can be implemented?

Comment: Just replace the `null` in the snippet above with `''`

Comment: very strange, the filed is now read only

Comment: Make sure the updater function actually runs

Answer (score 2):

**for typescript error**: you need to write the same type and just set value only if its not null, so type error won't bother you

```
const handleChange = (value: string | null) => {
  if (!value) {
    setStatus(value)
  } else setStatus('')
}

 
<Select
   labelId="status-label"
   id="status-helper"
   value={ticket.status || null}  // default value
   onChange={(event, value) => handleChange(value)}
   required
>
```

Comment: I tried the code but I get error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: handleChange is not defined
    at onChange (TicketProfile.tsx:257)
` when I select something from the Select list.

Answer (score 1):

First, in your `MenuItem`, set the `value` prop to object (`element`) instead of a string (`element.code`), this is because you pass an object as a value prop to your `Select`. The current `value` of the `Select` must have the same type as the `value` in `MenuItem`:

```
<Select
  labelId="status-label"
  id="status-helper"
  required
  value={status} // <------------------------- because value is an object here
  onChange={(e) => setStatus(e.target.value)}
>
  {ticketStatusList.map((element) => (
    <MenuItem
      key={element.code}
      value={element}  // <--- this one should be an object too as a result
    >
      {element.name}
    </MenuItem>
  ))}
</Select>
```

Then in your `status` state declaration, add a null object to change your `Select` to [controlled mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

```
const [status, setStatus] = useState<TicketStatusTypesDTO>({});
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: I get error: `TS2769: No overload matches this call.`

Comment: @PeterPenzov fork my codesandbox and put your code there, I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the optional chaining operator returns undefined. Try replacing

```
value={ticket?.status}
```

with

```
value={ticket?.status || null}
```

To solve the TypeScript error, in the useState hook, just declare all possible types of the state variable:

```
const [status, setStatus] = useState<string | null>("");
```

Comment: I tested the proposed fix but when I select a new value from the list the selected value is not updated.

Comment: You are using two different state variables: 'status' and 'ticket'. The 'value' property of Select should take the values from a state variable set in the 'onChange' callback: there are two choices:  1) set 'ticket.status' in the 'onChange'; 2) use the status variable to set the 'value' property:  'value={status}'.